# NHibernate joining in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, nhibernate

I have **Projects** in a hierarchy

```
Project1.Projects
     +- Project1.1
     +- Project1.2
Project2.Projects
     +- Project2.1
     +- Project2.2
Project3.Projects
     +- Project3.1
```

Users are assigned permissions on a project via a **UserProject**

```
User.Id --> UserProject.Id.UserId
            UserProject.Id.ProjectId --> Project.Id
```

(Yes, that's a composite ID, sorry... legacy database, what are you gonna do...)

Now, I need a list of all the top projects where a particular user have access to the project **or at least one of the subprojects**.

So if UserA have access to Project1 and Project3.1 I want to get a list containing Project1 and Project3 (*not 3.1*) preferably with some info that the user does not have permissions for Project3.

In the database the projects are stored flat with a parent link:

```
Project:
| Project_ID | Parent_project_id | HasSubProjects | ... |

UserProject
| ProjectID | UserId | other properties... |
```

Any suggestions on an effective way to get back what I want?

**Update**: I ended up with a massive SQL-statement using unions and hierarchical joins. Quite the beast. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to join your link table onto your project table, start with the set that your user directly has access to, and then traverse your tree using connect by prior:

```
    select ProjectID from UserProject u
inner join Project p
        on u.ProjectID = p.Project_ID
start with UserId = @foo
connect by prior Parent_Project_id = Project_ID
```

I don't have anything to test this on so there might be some syntax errors but that's the basic idea you want to use.

Comment: He'll have to use CreateSQLQuery() since NHibernate won't reconize `start with ... connect by prior`. That or depending how big his database his he could travel the tree manually.

Comment: No syntax errors, but it returned almost every UserProject record in the database (8.904.856 of 8.973.093) so there's something wrong there :) I'll look into it a bit more but for now I'm looking into just doing some separate lookups and counts. Never heard of the "connect by prior" though, thanks! Learned something new today as well.

Comment: Good point Mike.  I forgot to mention 'connect by prior' is an Oracle-specific syntax - so assuming your Oracle tag means you've got Oracle on the back end, you should be able to run it using PL/SQL or something.